# Css performance! more duplicate or unique

Tags: css, performance, class, browser, traffic

In large projects...

Which one is Faster and Optimized?

Which is better for browser and traffic?

*1.

```
.class1,.class2{
line-height:40px;
text-align:left;
margin-left:4%;
width:34%;
float:right
}
.class2{
width:44%;
float:left
}
```

2. 

```
.class1{
line-height:40px;
text-align:left;
margin-left:4%;
width:34%;
float:right
}
.class2{
line-height:40px;
text-align:left;
margin-left:4%;
width:44%;
float:left
}
```

*3.

```
.class1,.class2{
line-height:40px;
text-align:left;
margin-left:4%;
}
.class1{
width:34%;
float:right;
}
.class2{
width:44%;
float:left;
}
```

*new update suggested by @connexo.

Sepas for your time!

Comment: In you first rule block you have two declarations for `width`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'd do it. Put all properties both classes share in one block, then define deviating properties solo after that.

```
.class1, 
.class2 {
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-left: 4%;
    text-align: left;
}
.class1 {
    float: right;
    width: 34%;
}
.class2 {
    float: left;
    width: 44%;
}
```

Aside from that structural thing I'd recommend to sort the declarations alphabetically and do not omit the semi-colon after the last declaration in a block.

Comment: You right about semicolon. I never think to your model, because I think It's not mini! but I select that if performed for browser.

Comment: Against others not Minify but we have Gzip! So Best Answer Is 3.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the question is correct. In case of CSS, I would ask how easy it will be to maintain it. When you work on bigger websites, updating 1 piece of style declarations is better than updating 10 pieces of declarations. If you are sure that class1 and class 2 behavior will always be the same, I would go with the first example. It will be easier down the road to find what exactly needs to be updated.

Both examples will not affect the performance any noticeably, also, they have nothing to do with SEO (to the best of my knowledge).

I hope this answers the question...

Comment: I would go with the first example then. It is just really easier. When dealing with tons of styles for every container on your website, it is incredibly difficult to find the right piece that needs updating. Grouping them like this definitely helps.

Comment: You right if developers is important, but now traffic and browser are important.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you should pay attention to:

**1. Use shorthands**
This will reduce unnecessarily used space. --> Optimized the traffic

**2. Minify your code**
Same as for 1.

**3. Split up your CSS - Code (Critical Above the Fold CSS)**
This is a very effective way to optimize your page speed. You can put the code for the first view that the user can see at the top of your page and the rest at the bottom. Then the browser can render the page, without completely downloading the page.

**4. Use inline CSS**
This is not the beautifulest solution, but it can impair the performance. But do not write all of your CSS inline, only some small parts.

Comment: I work with first 3 options. they are about traffic, but browser? You know 4 is nostalgia.

Comment: 3 Speeds up your page the most (In order your JavaScript does not block the process). For users the page feels a lot more responsive. And 4 can help too. It can reduce your css because you apply it directly to the element. but you're right, the effect is not extreme.